# Basket of Fruits and Vegetables

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A basket contains six distinct fruits and seven distinct vegetables. In how many ways can we select from the basket a collection of four items that has at least one vegetable?

Answer (score 2):

$1.$ Compute the number of ways to select $4$ items with *no* restriction.

$2.$ Compute the number of ways to select $4$ fruit.

Now is it clear how to find the answer to your question?

Comment: (1) $\rightarrow\pmatrix{13\\4}$

Comment: (2) $\rightarrow \pmatrix{6\\4}$

Comment: Subtraction? ? ?

Comment: Yes it is right. A useful idea sometimes, count them all and take away the bad ones.

Comment: Well then what about a collection of items so that there are food of each type?

Comment: Same sort of thing. Now the bad ones are (i) all fruit and (ii) all vegetables. So we must  subtract $\binom{6}{4}+\binom{7}{4}$ from the number of "no restriction" choices. (Sorry, sticky b key on my keyboard!)